# Client Migration with Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

We have DL-180 G6 server with automatically shoutdown and beyond repair, that's why we plan to purchase another DL-380G9 server.

Now the DNS name of DL-180 is different then DL-380
Example DL-180 DNS is abc.com and DL-380 DNS is abc.net

I will create same user name and password in DL-380 same as DL-180.

But the client will not connect becoz of different DNS and different SSID.

if i change the domain name on one of client and put abc.net which is new one and put the DL-380 administrative passowrd it will added in new domain

what my question is after adding and restarting it will create a new user profile or stay same profile and only added to new server?

Thanks
Basit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reassign current profile on client's PC to other Windows Domain Controller by using personal edition version of program [ForensiT's User Profile Wizard 3.12](https://www.forensit.com/downloads.html).

I used this program and it worked well. No need to create new profiles. The program will unsubscribe from old Domain Controller, subscribe to new DC and change user's SID for local profile (with permissions). Important - you need to have worked local administrator's account on client's PC.

Comment: Many Thanks, but this software need to purchas or free of cost? Thanks Basit.

Comment: Personal edition is free.

Answer (score 0):

This will create a new profile on the client. Even if all the details of the two accounts remain the same(except for the few obvious ones like UPN, SID) the client will identify it as a different user and create a new profile.

Comment: Thanks A lot, then what is the solution that client should not affect?

Comment: Unless there is a need for a change of domain name, don't change it. Is the DL-180 the only DC and DNS server you had for abc.com? I would suggest make the DL-380 a part of the ABC.com domain

Comment: What our plan is we will remove DL-180G6 server and DL-380G9 will be primary server. Thanks Basit